# onChange method of Form_DropDown

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am using form_dropdown().But its onchange() function is not working.This is my simple code

```
$js ='onChange="message()"';
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" > function message(){ 
alert('hello');
</script>";
echo form_dropdown('name',$data,$js);
```

Comment: what is `form_dropdown()`?

Comment: @vimalnath It's a Codeigniter form helper function

Comment: @vimalnath A helper function of [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: In the future, use the JS console in your browsers (press F12 in IE >9, Chrome, Firefox with Firebug extension), it would have shown you the JS error on the page

Comment: its codeigniter form helper function but its onChange function is not working...I just want when i change the text in dropdown menu by selecting string it should appear a dialog box..

Comment: try changing variable `$js` to `$js = "onChange=message();"`

Comment: I have checked it @Hussain Tomboli but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

look like you miss `}` here

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" > function message(){ 
alert('hello');
</script>";
```

should be

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" > function message(){ 
alert('hello');
}
</script>";
```

**UPDATE**
I just check [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html), javascript should be the fourth param. The third one should be the default value

Comment: any live test site? It will be helpful if we can debug online

Comment: I don't have any idea about online sites..Would you please suggest me about some sites...

Comment: I mean it will be better if you could upload your site to online server

Comment: I have never touch codeigniter. I hope I could help you by look into your html output

Comment: Its does not giving me any error.Its simple show me one drop down menu which has some String value..But when i select some value from the dropdown menu it is not doing any thing but i want when i change the string in the drop down menu a simple javascript function will run and alert dialog box will appear...

Comment: does `onChange="message()"` appear in the select tag?

Comment: BTW, review the comment above.....the braces you should add should be `}`, not `{`

Comment: I just check http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html, javascript should be the fourth param. The third one should be the default value

Comment: Oh Realy thanks man....Yap i am missing the third parameter...Now its working fine....Can you give me favor to give me your email id so that when  i face any problem i can get u...

Comment: Well, I will suggest you ask in stackoverflow, so that many other ppl can help.

Comment: But there are many minor issues which seems bad to post on stackoverflow...but thats up to you...Any How thanks man for help.:)

Comment: Hope you could accept my answer. I need more reputation to let stackoverflow allow me leave comment~_~

Comment: actually, if you could post some more information, that will be helpful for us to find out the problem, for example, in the question, you can also post the html output and we could know that if the onChange event have been add to the `select` tag

Comment: if you have posted some question but no one help, you may leave a message here with the link to the question, I will try my best to answer

Answer (score 0):

If You  load the file on server and open in browser ; use view source code

```
<script type="text/javascript" > function message(){ 
alert('hello');
</script><br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function:  form_dropdown() in <b>/var/www/html/parag/synchro2/dddd.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

You will see } is missing just after alert('hello');

Comment: there is already a code available to try here. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html have you tried that? and you can check this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305302/codeigniter-dropdown-javascript   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708898/multiple-functions-with-form-dropdown-for-some-checked-checkboxes-in-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks...I have used both of these links..but these are not fullfill my requirements..

Comment: hopefully you have loaded helper $this->load->helper('form');  ..!!? can you go through this tutorial and give a try? http://www.maheshchari.com/codeigniter-form_dropdown/.

Comment: You have only 3 parameters in form_dropdown(); If you would like the opening <select> to contain additional data, like an id attribute or JavaScript, you can pass it as a string in the fourth parameter: FROM http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

```
echo form_dropdown('name', $data, '', $js);
```

You should use like that. 3rd parameter is Default Value